# $\sqrt[3]{\text{something}\pm\sqrt{\text{something}}}$

Tags: radicals, cubics

$$\sqrt{A\pm\sqrt{B}}=\sqrt{\frac{A+C}{2}}\pm\sqrt{\frac{A-C}{2}}$$
, where
$C^2=A^2-B$.
But, I couldn't find a formula for
$\sqrt[3]{A\pm\sqrt{B}}$.

First of all, why would you even need this? I've recently learned the cubic formula from Wikipedia. Let's consider the general cubic equation
$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$.
We have
$$\Delta_0=b^2-3ac$$
$$\Delta_1=2b^3-9abc+27a^2d$$
Then we calculate
$$C=\sqrt[3]{\frac{\Delta_1\pm\sqrt{\Delta_1^2-4\Delta_0^3}}{2}}$$
Whether we chose $+$ or $-$ is trivial because we are anyways going to get the same roots, regardless the order.

Then we have the final formula:
$$x_k=-\frac{1}{3a}\Big(b+C\omega^k+\frac{\Delta_0}{C\omega^k}\Big)$$
where
$\omega=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$
(primitive cube root of unity) and
$x \in \{0,1,2\}$.

I prefer to calculate the first 2 roots using the formula and the last root from Vieta's formula
$\sum x_k=-\frac{b}{a}$.

Let' take, for example, the following equation:
$$x^3+x-2=0$$
with
$$a=1,~b=0,~c=1,~d=-2$$
We have
$$\Delta_0=-3$$
$$\Delta_1=-54$$
And C simplifies to be
$$C=\sqrt[3]{-27+6\sqrt{21}}$$
I knew for sure the answer to this would be something of the form
$A+\sqrt{B}$
, with
$A,~B\in\mathbb{R}$.
So
$-27+6\sqrt{21}$
must be of the form
$(x+y)^3$
with
$x\in\mathbb{Q}$
and
$y\in\mathbb{I}$
(it's something with $\sqrt{21}$). Expanding the expression we get
$x^3+3x^2y+3xy^2+y^3=-27+6\sqrt{21}$. In this situation we can affirm that
$x^3+3xy^2\in\mathbb{Q}$
and
$y^3+3x^2y\in\mathbb{I}$.
Hence, we have the following system of equations
$$x^3+3xy^2=-27$$
$$y^3+3x^2y=6\sqrt{21}$$
I tried my guesses but nope, I couldn't find the solutions. I gave up and used WolframAlpha which immediately calculated it as
$\frac{-3+\sqrt{21}}{2}$.
So $x$ would be $-\frac{3}{2}$ and $y$ would be $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. I would have never thought of it. And solving the system by substitution, we have to substitute $y=\pm\sqrt{\frac{-x^3-27}{3x}}$ and that would lead to a monster equation, probably a hexic equation.

My question - is there a formula like the one for simple square roots? I couldn't find anything on the internet...

Comment: See [Denesting Phi, Denesting Cube Roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/550139/318073) for denesting $\sqrt[n]{A+B\sqrt[m]C}$.

Comment: Thanks, I understand it! Though, you have to solve another cubic equation to get to the answer :(

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4148105. In fact you have to solve another cubic equation and this involves finitely many trials - but it always works.