# Generalized denesting formula for $\sqrt[3]{A+B\sqrt{C}}$

Tags: radicals, cubics, nested-radicals

**Question**: What is the generalized formula for denesting

$$\sqrt[3]{A+B\sqrt{C}}$$

Recently I've posted a question about nested radicals in solving the cubic equation. I received a comment about an ingenious method to *denest* the radical by solving a cubic equation, but, I was still not satisfied. See [$\sqrt[3]{\text{something}\pm\sqrt{\text{something}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4179882/sqrt3something-pm-sqrtsomething) and the link from the comments [Denesting Phi, Denesting Cube Roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550121/denesting-phi-denesting-cube-roots/550139#550139).

Trying to solve cubic equations, sometimes I would get something like $\sqrt[3]{-27+6\sqrt{21}}$, which is not easily *denested* by hand. I had to go and solve **another cubic equation**. The radical derives from the equation $x^3+x-2=0$. The cubic equation I had to solve for the radical would be more complex than the equation itself. I tried searching the internet for a *denesting* formula but I couldn't find a definitive one. All I could find was something about Galois theory which is mathematics I don't understand (I'm a 10th grader in Romania).

So, I tried making my own algorithm. Based on the idea from [Denesting Phi, Denesting Cube Roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550121/denesting-phi-denesting-cube-roots/550139#550139), I might have generalized it to solving a *depressed* cubic equation, which should be relatively easy and, in lucky cases, immediate. Keep in mind this is not a formula, but a simplification.

See the answer below.

Answer (score 9):

$$\sqrt[3]{A+B\sqrt{C}}$$
We want to write
$A+B\sqrt{C}$
as
$(a+b\sqrt{C})^3$.
$$(a+b\sqrt{C})^3=(a^3+3ab^2C)+(b^3C+3a^2b)\sqrt{C}$$
$$\Rightarrow A+B\sqrt{C}=(a^3+3ab^2C)+(b^3C+3a^2b)\sqrt{C}$$
$$
\Rightarrow 
\begin{cases}
A=a^3+3ab^2C&(1) \\
B=b^3C+3a^2b&(2)
\end{cases}
$$
$$\text{Let}~\alpha=\frac{A}{B}\Rightarrow A=\alpha B.\text{ Multiply equation (2) by }\alpha\text{ and we get }$$
$$B\alpha=\alpha b^3C+3\alpha a^2b.\text{ But }B\alpha=A=a^3+3ab^2C$$
$$\Rightarrow a^3+3ab^2C=\alpha b^3C+3\alpha a^2b$$
$$\text{Dividing by }b^3\text{ we get }\Big(\frac{a}{b}\Big)^3+3C\Big(\frac{a}{b}\Big)=3\alpha\Big(\frac{a}{b}\Big)^3+\alpha C.$$
$$\text{ Make the notation }w=\frac{a}{b}\text{ so }w^3+3Cw=3\alpha w^3+\alpha C.$$
$$\text{Moving terms to the left hand side we have }\underbrace{1}_aw^3\underbrace{-3\alpha}_b w^2\underbrace{+3C}_cw\underbrace{-\alpha C}_d=0.$$
$$
\text{Solve the cubic equation using the cubic formula. I have emphasized the coefficients above.}
$$
$$\Delta_0=b^2-3ac=9(\alpha^2-C)$$
$$\Delta_1=2b^3-9abc+27a^2d=-54\alpha(\alpha^2-C)$$
$$\text{Now calculate the cubic constant }$$
$$\mathcal{C}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{\Delta_1\pm\sqrt{\Delta_1^2-4\Delta_0^3}}{2}}$$
$$\text{ Note this }\mathcal{C}\text{ is not the }C\text{ from the nested radical! }$$
$$\sqrt{\Delta_1^2-4\Delta_0^3}=\sqrt{\big(-54\alpha(\alpha^2-C)\big)^2-4\big(9(\alpha^2-C)\big)^3}=\sqrt{54^2(\alpha^2-C)^2\big(\alpha^2-(\alpha^2-C)\big)}$$
$$\sqrt{\Delta_1^2-4\Delta_0^3}=54|\alpha^2-C|\sqrt{C}$$
$$\mathcal{C}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{-54\alpha(\alpha^2-C)\pm54|\alpha^2-C|\sqrt{C}}{2}}$$
$$\text{But the }\pm\text{ and the }|\alpha^2-C|\text{ go meh and we are left with }$$
$$\mathcal{C}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{-54\alpha(\alpha^2-C)\pm54(\alpha^2-C)\sqrt{C}}{2}}$$
$$\text{Let's consider the }-\text{ solution because we will have}-54\text{ common factor and we will be left only with }+\text{ inside the radical. }\mathcal{C}\text{ simplifies to be}$$
$$\mathcal{C}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{-54(\alpha^2-C)(\alpha-\sqrt{C})}{2}}=-3\sqrt[3]{(\alpha^2-C)(\alpha+\sqrt{C})}$$
$$\text{One of the roots will have the formula }w=-\frac{1}{3a}\Big(b+\mathcal{C}+\frac{\Delta_0}{\mathcal{C}}\Big).$$
$$\frac{\Delta_0}{\mathcal{C}}=\frac{9(\alpha^2-C)}{-3\sqrt[3]{(\alpha^2-C)(\alpha^2-\sqrt{C})}}=-3\frac{(\alpha+\sqrt{C})(\alpha-\sqrt{C})}{\sqrt[3]{\alpha+\sqrt{C}}\sqrt[3]{(\alpha-\sqrt{C})^2}}$$
$$\text{We have }\frac{z}{\sqrt[3]{z}}=\sqrt[3]{z^2}\text{ and }\frac{z}{\sqrt[3]{z^2}}=\sqrt[3]{z}\text{ by rationalizing.}$$
$$\text{For }z=\alpha+\sqrt{C}\text{ and }z=\alpha-\sqrt{C}\text{ respectively we obtain }$$
$$\frac{\Delta_0}{\mathcal{C}}=-3\sqrt[3]{(\alpha^2+C)(\alpha-\sqrt{C})}$$
$$w=-\frac{1}{3}\Big(-3\alpha-3\sqrt[3]{(\alpha^2-C)(\alpha-\sqrt{C})}-3\sqrt[3]{(\alpha^2-C)(\alpha+\sqrt{C})}\Big)$$
$$w=\alpha+\sqrt[3]{\alpha^2-C}\Big(\sqrt[3]{\alpha-\sqrt{C}}+\sqrt[3]{\alpha+\sqrt{C}}\Big)$$
$$
\text{Make the following notations: }
\begin{cases}
R=\sqrt[3]{\alpha^2-C} \\
T=\underbrace{\sqrt[3]{\alpha-\sqrt{C}}}_p+\underbrace{\sqrt[3]{\alpha+\sqrt{C}}}_q
\end{cases}
$$
$$\text{We will work on }T.~T^3=(p+q)^3=p^3+q^3+3pq(p+q).$$
$$p^3+q^3=2\alpha$$
$$3pq(p+q)=3\sqrt[3]{\alpha^2-C}\cdot T=3RT$$
$$T^3=2\alpha+3RT\Rightarrow T^3-3RT-2\alpha=0$$
$$\mathbf{And~here~we~stop.}$$
This is a *depressed* equation which should be OK to solve by hand. We will suppose $T$ is calculated through this equation. Hence, we have calculated: $\alpha$, $R$ and $T$ and should be able to go for $w=\alpha+RT$. Coming back to our system of equations, we have $\frac{a}{b}=w\Rightarrow a=wb$, and by substituting in $(2)$ we get
$$B=3w^2b^3+Cb^3\Rightarrow b^3(3w^2+C)=B\Rightarrow b=\sqrt[3]{\frac{B}{3w^2+C}}$$
$$B=b^3C+3a^2b\Rightarrow 3a^2b=B-b^3C\Rightarrow a=\pm\sqrt{\frac{B-b^3C}{3b}}$$
$$\mathbf{And~these~are~the~final~formulas.}$$
Let's recap the algorithm for $\sqrt[3]{A+B\sqrt{C}}$. We have
$$
\begin{cases}
\alpha=\frac{A}{B} \\
R=\sqrt[3]{\alpha^2-C} \\
T^3-3RT-2\alpha=0 \\
w=\alpha+RT \\
b=\sqrt[3]{\frac{B}{3w^2+C}} \\
a=\pm\sqrt{\frac{B-b^3C}{3b}}
\end{cases}
$$
Let's take for example $\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{5}}$.
$$
\begin{cases}
A=2 \\
B=1 \\
C=5 \\
\alpha=2 \\
R=-1 \\
T^3+3T-4=0\Rightarrow T=1\text{ (obvious)} \\
w=1 \\
b=\frac{1}{2} \\
a=\frac{1}{2}
\end{cases}
$$
Our final form is $a+b\sqrt{C}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{5}$. So $\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{5}}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{5}$.

Another example: $\sqrt[3]{7+5\sqrt{2}}$.
$$
\begin{cases}
A=7 \\
B=5 \\
C=2 \\
\alpha=\frac{7}{5} \\
R=-\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{25}}=-\frac{\sqrt[3]{5}}{5} \\
T^3+\frac{3\sqrt[3]{5}}{5}T-\frac{14}{5}=0\Leftrightarrow5T^3+3\sqrt[3]{5}T-14=0 \\
\end{cases}
$$
$$T\text{ will be of the form }\frac{k}{\sqrt[3]{5}}\Rightarrow k^3+3k-14=0.\text{ By trial we get }k=2\text{ and }T=\frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{5}}$$
$$
\begin{cases}
w=1 \\
b=1 \\
a=1
\end{cases}
$$
Conclusion: $\sqrt[3]{7+5\sqrt{2}}=1+\sqrt{2}$

Let's see the example from the question: $\sqrt[3]{-27+6\sqrt{21}}$
$$
\begin{cases}
A=-27 \\
B=6 \\
C=21 \\
\alpha=-\frac{9}{2} \\
R=-\frac{\sqrt[3]{3}}{\sqrt[3]{2}}=-\frac{\sqrt[3]{6}}{2} \\
T^3+\frac{3\sqrt[3]{6}}{2}T+9=0\Leftrightarrow2T^3+3\sqrt[3]{6}T+18=0 \\
\end{cases}
$$
$$T\text{ will be of the form }\frac{k}{\sqrt[3]{6}}\Rightarrow\frac{k^3}{3}+3k+18=0\Leftrightarrow k^3+9k+54=0.$$
$$k\text{ must be negative.}$$
$$\text{For }-1\text{ and }-2\text{ we get }44\text{ and }28\text{ respectively.}$$
$$\text{It feels like we're approaching the answer. Let's try }-3\text{ and we get identity.}$$
$$k=-3\text{ with }T=-\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{6}}$$
$$
\begin{cases}
w=-3 \\
b=\frac{1}{2} \\
a=-\frac{3}{2}\text{ (notice that we used the negative solution)}
\end{cases}$$
Thus, $\sqrt[3]{-27+6\sqrt{21}}=-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{21}}{2}$.

FINAL NOTES

- I am a high school student. I have no real experience with math. I have no idea how correct these things are.
- I am aware there is a whole documentation on nested radicals (Galois theory), but it was fun deducing these formulas on my own.
- I couldn't find one, but there might be another simpler formula for this on the internet.
- If one were to seriously interpret this, I hope it's inspiration for future proofs and formulas.
- I would like to see criticism. It's my first time doing this kind of formula deducing.

Signed by Neox

Comment: I am sorry for the bad formatting. In the preview it looked much more clear.

Comment: Please review *carefully* the current policy of [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1), which now applies to not only askers, but also the answerers that answer very low quality questions.

Comment: I am well aware of the poor context of my question, Aaron Hendrickson. Although, I specificed that the idea originates from another post of mine, where I was asking for such a formula. There, I received a comment with a post where the denesting is solved for a particular radical, which inspired me to generalize it. I am kind of new to the forum and I didn't take my time to strictly read all the rules. Also, when I considered to make the post, I wouldn't categorize the idea as *very low quality*, since I've seen many other posts on this topic and to be honest they didn't seem too complicated.

Comment: I see just now that you both were the questioner and answerer. The motivation of my comment is that we have seen a great influx of low quality questions (usually HW problems with no attempt), followed up with answers. This creates a perverse incentive for more bad questions. But in this case since you performed both tasks (great answer btw) and so I'm not sure my earlier comment applies.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson I see now that you have misunderstood the post. Though I appreciate that you took your time to redirect me to the posting rules FAQ. See the good part - I've learned something new!

Comment: And for those who want to practice denesting and check the answers: http://musiclifephilosophy.com/codes/cube-root-denest/. That's a joke obviously.

Answer (score 2):

Thr denest formula is

$$\sqrt[3]{A+B \sqrt C}=\frac12\sqrt[3]{3Bs+2A}\left(1+\frac {\sqrt C}{s+A/B}\right)$$
with $s$ satisfying the depressed cubic equation
$$s^3+3(C-\frac{A^2}{B^2})s +\frac{2A}B (C-\frac{A^2}{B^2}) =0$$

For $\sqrt[3]{-27+6\sqrt{21}}
$, one has
$s^3+\frac94s-\frac{27}4=0$ and $s=\frac32$, leading to the denesting
$$\sqrt[3]{-27+6\sqrt{21}}
= \frac12\sqrt[3]{18s-54}\left(1+ \frac{\sqrt {21}}{s+ 7/2}\right)
=-\frac32+\frac12\sqrt{21}
$$

Answer (score 0):

OP's example is one of the cases covered by my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4447889/291201).

> Therefore a sufficient condition for $\,a,b = \sqrt[3]{m \sqrt{p} \pm n\sqrt{q}}\,$ to denest is for $\,m^2 \cdot p - n^2 \cdot q\,$ to be the cube of a rational $\,r\,$, and for the cubic $\,p\, t'^{\,3} - 3r\, t' - 2m\,$ to have an appropriate rational root, and in that case $\,a,b = \frac{1}{2}\left(t'\,\sqrt{p} \pm \sqrt{t'^{\,2} p-4r}\right)\,$.

For $\,a,b = \sqrt[3]{-27 \pm 6\sqrt{21}}\,$:

- $m=-27\,$, $\,p=1\,$, $\,n=\pm 6\,$, $\,q=21\,$;
- $m^2 \cdot p - n^2 \cdot q$ $= (-27)^2 - (\pm 6)^2 \cdot 21$ $= -27$ $=(-3)^3$ $\implies r=-3\,$;
- $0 = p\, t'^{\,3} - 3r\, t' - 2m = t'^{\,3} + 9 t' + 54\,$ with the only real root $\,t' = -3\,$.

Then:

$$
a,b = \frac{1}{2}\left(t'\,\sqrt{p} \pm \sqrt{t'^{\,2} p - 4r}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(-3 \cdot 1 \pm \sqrt{(-3)^2 \cdot 1 - 4 \cdot (-3)}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(-3 \pm \sqrt{21}\right) 
$$