# Evaluating $\sqrt[3]{x_1}+\sqrt[3]{x_2}$

Tags: polynomials

Consider the following quadratic equation:

$$x^2-4x-1 = 0 \tag{1}$$

Whose solutions are denoted by $x_1, x_2\in \mathbb{R}$.  Then by using the fact that $x_1+x_2 = 4$ and $x_1x_2 = -1$, how can we evaluate $\sqrt[3]{x_1}+\sqrt[3]{x_2}$?

$$\begin{align}\biggr(\sqrt[3]{x_1}+\sqrt[3]{x_2}\biggr)^3 &= x_1+3(\sqrt[3]{x_1})^2\sqrt[3]{x_2}+3(\sqrt[3]{x_1})(\sqrt[3]{x_2})^2 + x_2\\\ &= (x_1+x_2) + 3(\sqrt[3]{x_1})^2(\sqrt[3]{x_2})+3(\sqrt[3]{x_1})(\sqrt[3]{x_2})^2 \\\ &= 4+3\biggr((\sqrt[3]{x_1})^2(\sqrt[3]{x_2})+(\sqrt[3]{x_1})(\sqrt[3]{x_2})^2\biggr) \\\ &= 4+3\biggr((\sqrt[3]{x_1})\sqrt[3]{x_1x_2} +(\sqrt[3]{x_2})\sqrt[3]{x_1x_2}\biggr)  \\\ &= 4-3\biggr(\sqrt[3]{x_1}+\sqrt[3]{x_2}\biggr) \tag{2}\end{align}$$

However, I am not sure where this would lead us. Could I hear your feedback, if possible?

Comment: How did you get from third line to fourth line in (2)?

Comment: I updated the question to include more clarification.

Answer (score 3):

If you mark $t=\sqrt[3]{x_1}+\sqrt[3]{x_2}$ you have to solve $$t^3 = 4-3t$$ which shouldn't be hard (using say rational root theorem).

---

Or if $y_i =\sqrt[3]{x_i}$ then you need $y_1+y_2$ knowing $y_1y_1 =-1$ and $y_1^3+y_2^3=4$. From last one you have $$4=(y_1+y_2)(y_1^2-y_1y_2+y_2^2) = t(t^2-3y_1y_2) = t(t^2+3)$$

so you get the same equation.

Comment: @nouser I think you have to mention which of the three roots in terms of t is the actual value of the sum of cube roots. Like t = 0, sqrt(3)i,-sqrt(3)i

Answer (score 0):

Alt. hint: $\,$ the roots of the quadratic are $\,x_{1,2} = 2 \pm \sqrt{5}\,$, and $\,\sqrt[3]{x_{1,2}}$ $= \sqrt[3]{2 \pm \sqrt{5}}$ $= \frac{1}{2}\left(1 \pm \sqrt{5}\right)\,$, see [Denesting Phi, Denesting Cube Roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550121/denesting-phi-denesting-cube-roots), or [Generalized denesting formula for $\sqrt[3]{A+B\sqrt{C}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4180334/generalized-denesting-formula-for-sqrt3ab-sqrtc/).